# How do I query time-period values for continuous data?

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got records that indicate when a job starts and when it ends. The End time is not recorded until the job ends, but the start time exists from the time the job starts. What I want is to know how many jobs were running in a given time period.

```
declare @data table (
    JobId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    StartedAt DATETIME NOT NULL,
    EndedAt DATETIME NULL
)
insert into @data (StartedAt, EndedAt) 
select '1 Jan 2010 8:00', '1 Jan 2010 8:30'
union select '1 Jan 2010 8:00', '1 Jan 2010 9:00'
union select '1 Jan 2010 8:00', '1 Jan 2010 9:20'
union select '1 Jan 2010 9:00', '1 Jan 2010 9:20'
union select '1 Jan 2010 9:10', NULL
```

Given the above, how would I query the number of jobs running in each hour? I would expect the results to indicate that there were 3 jobs running in the 8:00 through 8:59 time period, and 4 running in the 9:00 through 9:59 period, as follows:

```
Time period     Jobs
08:00..08:59    3
09:00..09:59    4
```

I can modify the schema and I have *some* influence over how data is recorded if that would make the query simpler or more efficient.Blockquote

Comment: How many distinct periods will you want to query simultaneously?

Comment: As many as 24 at one time, but another query for 7. I.e. we'd want the past 24 hours, and the past seven days.

Answer (score 0):

Without spending huge amounts of time on the problem, I'd suggest the simplest solution would be to create a table of days, and a table of hours (then you have a table of hours and days by creating a cartesian join) e.g.

days (ondate not null)
slots (start_time time not null, end_time no_null)

then identifying the number of jobs which had a start or end time within those slots:

```
SELECT days.ondate, slots.start_time, slots.end_time, (
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @data
   WHERE (@data.start_time BETWEEN
       STR_TO_DATE(
          CONCATENATE(DATE_FORMAT(days.ondate, 'YYYYMMDD'),
             DATE_FORMAT(slots.start_time,'HH24MISS')), 
          'YYYYMMDDHH25MISS')
     AND
       STR_TO_DATE(
          CONCATENATE(DATE_FORMAT(days.ondate, 'YYYYMMDD'),
             DATE_FORMAT(slots.end_time,'HH24MISS')), 
          'YYYYMMDDHH25MISS')
  ) OR (@data.start_time BETWEEN
          CONCATENATE(DATE_FORMAT(days.ondate, 'YYYYMMDD'),
             DATE_FORMAT(slots.start_time,'HH24MISS')), 
          'YYYYMMDDHH25MISS')
     AND
       STR_TO_DATE(
          CONCATENATE(DATE_FORMAT(days.ondate, 'YYYYMMDD'),
             DATE_FORMAT(slots.end_time,'HH24MISS')), 
          'YYYYMMDDHH25MISS')
  ) AS jobs_running
  FROM days, slots
  ;
```

Of course this is going to get very inefficient very quickly - so you might want to think about pre-aggregation.